# Python User Interface Print Statements

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm writing a CLI helper program for managing a video library. Is it better to keep any kind of print statements in a single module, passing data via return statements, or simply print my output when I need to, where I need to?

Comment: If "a CLI helper program" means what I think it does, I've recently made one myself in Python, and would be willing to release it as OSS (right now it's bundled in with a larger project that won't be, but that I still have rights to)... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `return` statements properly for returning Outputs from function calls so that your I/O interfaces between functions are clear and meaningful. If you want debugging, use `logging` module and when your program is development phases, you can use print statements in between too.

Comment: Moreover: if you or someone else decides to upgadeyour program to give it a GUI, your current functions won't need to be touched

Comment: I'm not sure if I should move this to a separate question, but the issue I was having with using a return statement versus a print statement was that after printing out the information, a single "None" was printed at the very end. I'm not sure why.

Comment: sensae: if your function does not return anything and then you try to print the function call. It will print `None` because when return value is not specified python gives it a `None`. I think that's what is happening in your case.